# Server and client program stops for unknown reason

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a simple client/server program that takes client into the server and gives it back to the user then queries the user for another input. The problem is though, that for some reason the program keeps waiting after the first input and it doesn't even send the input to the server at that. Any help would be much appreciated.

SERVER CODE

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Server {
    public static final String ENDLINE = "\r\n";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000)){
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
            Socket clientConnection = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("connection accepted from: "+ clientConnection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            OutputStream clientOutputStream = clientConnection.getOutputStream();
            InputStream clientInputStream = clientConnection.getInputStream();
            String msg = String.format("Hello: %s tell me something: ", clientConnection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            clientOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

            while(true){
                StringBuilder clientMessage = new StringBuilder();
                int c = clientInputStream.read();
                while(c != -1){
                    clientMessage.append((char)c);
                    c = clientInputStream.read();
                }
                String clientMessageString = String.valueOf(clientMessage);
                String returnMsg = String.format("Okay got your message: %s, anything else? ",clientMessageString);
                clientOutputStream.flush();
                if (clientMessageString.equals("quit")) break;
            }clientConnection.close();
        }catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

CLIENT CODE

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",2000)){
            InputStream inputFromServer = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            Reader newRead = new InputStreamReader(inputFromServer);
            OutputStream toServer = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            int c = newRead.read();
            while(true) {
                while (c != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) c);
                    c = newRead.read();
                }
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("> ");
                String keyboardInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                toServer.write(keyboardInput.getBytes());
                toServer.flush();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see your program gets stuck trying to receive information from the server. The `inputFromServer`stream is never terminated and the client just keeps blocking on `newRead.read()` waiting for new input.

Comment: I think that the inputStream is blocking because the client isn't sending more date, but the socket is still open. I think you'd have a better shot at using BufferedReader for reading input.

Comment: Read the Javadoc for InputStreamReader.read(). The 'end of the stream' means when it has been closed. Try terminating your while loop when you've read a complete message.